# How can I make it dynamic

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-2.7, urllib2

I have this code that I want to optimize, because it start it to gain volume :( . I want to make an array and call the values from him, instead of creating code for each object like I'm doing now :

```
post_data_groups = {'profile': '46', 'clear': 'Remove+Avatar'}
post_data_documents = {'folder1': '30', 'remove': 'Delete+Documents'}

urlAdmin_groups = 'http://site.com/management.php?Category=6&uid=196'
urlModerator_groups = 'http://site.com/management.php?Category=6&uid=197'
..........
```

and then for Documents:

```
urlAdmin_documents = 'http://site.com/management.php?Category=3&uid=196'
urlModerator_documents = 'http://site.com/management.php?Category=3&suid=197'
.... and so on
data_groups= urllib.urlencode(post_data_groups)
data_documents= urllib.urlencode(post_data_documents)
```

Then I call them like this:

```
response = opener.open(urlAdmin_groups, data_groups)
response = opener.open(urlAdmin_documents, data_documents)
........... and so on
the_page = response.read()
```

How I can make loop in calling them since only the category and uid changes?

Answer (score 3):

Basically it's a great use case for the [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in function:

```
url = 'http://site.com/management.php?Category={cat}&uid={uid}'
cat_uids = [ (3,196), (3,197), ... ] # read thos from config file or...
urls = [ url%cat_uid for cat_uid in cat_uids ]
responses = map(opener.open, urls)
pages = map(response_class.read,responses) # where response_class is the class returned by open()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a string as a template:

```
url = 'http://site.com/management.php?Category={cat}&uid={uid}'
```

then you can use the `.format()` method of strings to fill in the slots:

```
response = opener.open(url.format(cat=3, uid=196), data))
the_page = response.read()
```

You'll have to expand this to using a loop, where you iterate over *something* that then provides the category and the UID, but you get the idea. Perhaps a mapping would work:

```
groups = {
    Admin: {'cat': 3, 'uid': 196},
    ...
}

for groupname, urlvalues in groups.iteritems():
    response = opener.open(url.format(**urlvalues), data_groups))
```

where the `**` format applies a dictionary as a set of keyword arguments; using `.format(**urlvalues)` essentially translates to `.format(cat=urlvalues['cat'], uid=urlvalues['uid'])`.

Comment: i tried something but i didnt found the magic solution. Can you offer me an example of a loop ?